# Error on DBMS output while printing text and calculated result using PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm using Oracle SQL developer making PL/SQL code.
My code is to print the data by using a mathematical formula in DBMS_Output.
However, codes starting with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is all grey and doesn't print anything.
I'm already using DBMS output by clicking view -> DBMS output -> plus -> connect to the server so I don't think disabled DBMS output is not the problem.
Can you help me out?

```
DECLARE
type Receipt is record(
productID PRODUCTS.PRODUCTID%type,
productName PRODUCTS.PRODUCTNAME%type,
numOfProduct PRODUCTS.UNITSONORDER%type,
unitPrice PRODUCTS.UNITPRICE%type);
receipt Receipt;
BEGIN
    select PRODUCTID,PRODUCTNAME, UNITSONORDER, UNITPRICE
    into receipt
    from PRODUCTS where PRODUCTID = 1;
    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product ID : '|| receipt.productID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Name : '|| receipt.productName);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of orders : '|| receipt.numOfProduct);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('Unit price : '|| receipt.unitPrice);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('sub-total'|| receipt.unitPrice);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('Taxes = '|| receipt.unitPrice*(13/100));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('Total Payment = '|| receipt.unitPrice*(13/100)+(receipt.unitPrice));
END;
```

Comment: You should be getting a number of syntax errors when you try to run that code.  Starting with `ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:
PLS-00371: at most one declaration for 'RECEIPT' is permitted
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:`

Comment: Just a little note about case in object names. Oracle is **non case sensitive for names** Thus `receipt` and `Receipt` are the same and  refer to the same objects.  (internally they are folded to upper case.). That is what leads to the redefinition ( PLS-00371: ) error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting a number of syntax errors when you attempt to run this code because you can't declare a record type `receipt` and declare a local variable `receipt`.  Only one declaration of `receipt` is allowed.  Perhaps you're coming from a programming language that is case-sensitive where `Receipt` and `receipt` would be different identifiers?

If we change the type declaration to a different identifier, `receipt_rec`, then your code mostly compiles.  You just have an issue on the final `dbms_output` call because Oracle thinks you're trying to add everything to the left of the `+` sign to the value on the right of the `+` sign rather than doing the arithmetic and then concatenating that to the string text.  I'd wrap the whole calculation in a `to_char` but it would be sufficient just to add parenthesis to force the order of operations you want.  Normally, it would make more sense to do the numeric calculation into a separate local variable and just print that local variable out.

```
DECLARE
type Receipt_rec is record(
  productID PRODUCTS.PRODUCTID%type,
  productName PRODUCTS.PRODUCTNAME%type,
  numOfProduct PRODUCTS.UNITSONORDER%type,
  unitPrice PRODUCTS.UNITPRICE%type);
receipt Receipt_rec;
BEGIN
    select PRODUCTID,PRODUCTNAME, UNITSONORDER, UNITPRICE
    into receipt
    from PRODUCTS where PRODUCTID = 1;
    
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product ID : '|| receipt.productID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Name : '|| receipt.productName);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of orders : '|| receipt.numOfProduct);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('Unit price : '|| receipt.unitPrice);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('sub-total'|| receipt.unitPrice);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('Taxes = '|| receipt.unitPrice*(13/100));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_Line('Total Payment = '|| ( receipt.unitPrice*(13/100)+(receipt.unitPrice) ));
END;
/
```

Here's [a dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81164f4f85d0730a1860d77fb9b437b9)